# Saving result of COUNT() sql query into variable in powershell

Tags: sql, variables, powershell, count, sqlcmd

I am running an sql query that will save the result into a csv. The only thing in the csv is the return of a COUNT() function. Is there a way that I can save this number directly into a variable in powershell?

Comment: Vutukuri, since the result is in a CSV it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be simple. Let's assume the CSV field is called `Result`:

```
$result = (Import-Csv .\sqlout.csv).Result
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without creating the csv in sqlcmd?

Comment: You could use the SqlServerCmdletSnapin. Look for it in `Get-PSSnapin -Registered` and add it with `Add-PSSnapin`.

Comment: Not as familiar with sqlcmd.exe but if you can get it to output a single number like `12` then just do this `$result = sqlcmd.exe ...`.  To force the result to a number (instead of a string): `[int]$result = sqlcmd.exe ...`.

Comment: the result would be something along the lines of
    accounts
    12

Comment: In that case `$sqlout = sqlcmd.exe ...; $result = $sqlout.Split(' ')[1]`.  This splits on a space and grabs the second element in the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the CSV you could use the SqlServerCmdletSnapin:

```
Add-PSSnapIn SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
(Invoke-Sqlcmd -server .\sqlexpress -database foo -query 'SELECT COUNT(...) FROM ...')[0]
```

Comment: This worked for me without the "Add-PSSnapIn SqlServerCmdletSnapin100" part